# Why can't I add text in a container with an image? (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 Container(
                  height: 120.0,
                  width: 120.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1298446861783556096/KjBCrY3L_400x400.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      child: const Text('@michael'),
                    ),
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  ),
```

I was expecting both text and image however there is a red line on text

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
 Container(
                  height: 120.0,
                  width: 120.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1298446861783556096/KjBCrY3L_400x400.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ),
                    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  ),
                  child: const Text('@michael'),
),
```